# Where to start to create an HTML website with 2 tables read from csv files using anything but php

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, csv

I want to design a website which displays on loading two tables each with it's respective data from a CSV file. Then every minute the website automatically refreshes.

This problem seems so simple! But yet the solution eludes me.

All of the files will be contained in 1 directory, not on a server but on a local machine. Such as sitting on the desktop. I understand if I use Javascript I have to use ADO, and I'm still trying to work out how to use ASP. I am new with both languages. So far the only restriction is that I can't use PHP.

So the jist so far as I can think right now is:

1. read the file
2. place the file into an array by splitting at the commas
3. write the array into td's ?
4. then print all this out into a div ?

I have googled my heart out and can't seem to find what I'm looking for. or even piece together what I'm looking for. Everything with javascript and ADO's leads me to dead ends, I can't find anything on ASP that is helpful.

Could someone please write up some sample code for a resource? Or have a better solution?

Comment: You say "not on a server".  But if you want this website to be accessible over the internet, some kind of server is required.  can you clarify?

Comment: How much control do you have over the input file format?   If you can get an XML source then it would be really easy to use a stylesheet to render the desired output...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will be much help but have a look at the [Microsoft TechNet Script Center](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/scriptcenter/default.aspx)

But as Matthew Flaschen has stated you will need to work out where the HTML will reside.  either local or on a server.

Other Useful Resources
[Read a CSV File Using Database Techniques](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/8b5b7875-fb3b-4ebe-8d6c-855725fc0ee4)
[Parsing Comma-Separated-Values Logs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176692.aspx)
[Write Text To Files](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198715.aspx)